# Save value of Id in other field sqlalchemy flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am creating a table in database using flask sqlalchemy

In models.py,

```
Class User(model):
    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    du_id = Column(Integer)
    name = Column (NVARCHAR(20))
    #other fields...
```

In this table, when inserting new record, the user_id is created automatically.

How to save the user_id value in du_id field automatically when creating/inserting new record?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to duplicate the same data?

Comment: Just for reference to check

Comment: Is there is a way to do that automatically when inserting new record

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hybrid attribute instead of a new column

```
class User(model):
    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column (NVARCHAR(20))
    #other fields...

    @hybrid_property
    def length(self):
        return self.user_id
```